# Problem with google assistant on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, home-assistant

When trying to run "googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk" on my Raspberry I get this error.
Anyone know how to fix this?

ImportError: /home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_exchange_8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the google cloud vision library.  This fixed it for me:

```
pip3 install 'grpcio==1.23.0' --force-reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around is to add:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0
```

Or whatever libatomic version you have.

e.g.:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0
python3 some_script_using_grpcio.py
```